# Problem with navigation flow(home > target page ->login- > back to target -> home(problem))

Tags: flutter, dart

I've made a home page and a target page.
When the a target page button is pushed on the home screen,
I am checking if users are logged in and navigating them to a Login Page(Web).
After successful Login, the page is redirecting back to a target Page.
Here comes a problem. There is no way back to the Home Page.

Home -> Target Page -> Log-in(Web) -> back to Target Page(No histories left in navigator)

I am using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(route)`

No Appbar back button. physical device back button directs to go out from the app now.
Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: This is strange. The normal behaviour is for the navigation stack to remain until popped. Pressing the back button *should* take you to the previous route. Is Navigator.of(context).pop() being called anywhere?

Comment: I think you are very new to Flutter.. check this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation

Answer (score 1):

To help return to the previous screen

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

Or read more about navigation in Flutter:
[Navigation and routing](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation)

Comment: for better answer , add an link to information about navigation in Flutter

Comment: When I use this pop() the user will go back to Log-in page and they need to log in again

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

or

[check this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation)

Comment: Your answer is the same as mine

Comment: When I use this pop() the user will go back to Log-in page and they need to log in again